# WARNING when adding UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add an `UIImagePickerController` and i get an `incompatible type 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>'` compiler warning. I need to know why? and a solution for it.

.m

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
```

.h

```
@interface GobblesViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong)UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
```

[image: compiler warning]

The warning point to  `[imagePicker setDelegate:self];` and i have no clue why this is occurring.

Answer (score 10):

You're getting this warning because the object, `self` in this case, that you're passing in to `UIImagePickerController`'s `delegate` property, doesn't conform to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` ***and*** `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocols. This is because `UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` which already declares it's own `delegate`.

The `delegate` property on `UIImagePickerController` is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Which means it is anticipating any object that conforms to those two protocols.

The `@interface` declaration for your class should be...

```
@interface GobblesViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```